# Load data from external web site

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load some specific info from external web site, and display it on my own html page. What is the best way to do that?

I tried to do that way:

```
function displayData(){
    $.get("http://www.website.com", function(response) { 
        var info = $(data).find(".specific-class").text();
        console.log(info);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
       displayData();
    });

});
```

This get request returns the whole html.
I need to display for example only specific text/info - `<div class="specific-class"> text </div>`

But this way is not working.
Or should I parse the whole html and find required parts?
Pls advise, how to solve the issue?

Comment: Please provide a complete sample of the code you're using. Is the second snippet of code inside the callback of the first snippet?

Comment: Is this site on the same domain as yours? Or does the site you're pulling from have the header settings to allow it to be accessed from another domain?

Comment: Provided complete sample of code

Comment: This site is different domain, anyway, I do not face with cors issues right now. I just want to explore, hiw can I select data from any web site and for example display it on my own resource

Answer (score 0):

So... In line with others. Make sure you don't have a cross-site origin issue.
If you have a cross site origin request issue, you'll be able to see it in the console when it happens. It will look something like:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://google.com/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

If that is not the case, I found another odd issue that could be causing your problem; and a way around it.

It appears that loading html from another page has an odd issue of not being able to search for items in the root level. (IE If it is a direct child of the body tag.) I do not know currently why this is, but it seems to treat all children of the body tag as a string. I worked through this with a `jquery.each` as in the sample below to get it. Someone may have a better explanation as to why this happens or a better way to get around it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#go").on("click", function() {
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/sa_support/index.html?v=4", function(data) {
            var input = $(data);
            var found = input.find(".cake");
            console.log(found.length);
            input.each(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass("cake")) {
                    console.log("Found it in the top level.");
                    found = found.add($(this));
                }
            });

            console.log(found.length);
        });
    });
});
```

In the case that the HTML loaded is as below, it will find it with the normal jQuery method.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="dist/build.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="custom" class="cake" value="aaa"/>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if the content is like this one, it will not find the tag using the normal methods. The each loop picks this up separately.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="dist/build.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <input type="text" id="custom" class="cake" value="aaa"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems like a bug in jQuery to me, but maybe it isn't? I don't really know on this one.

**Invalid HTML?**

If this is still not your issue, it is possible that the website you are loading is not outputting valid HTML. If that is the case, I don't know that jQuery can fix it for you.